# Import all existing keyspaces schemas

Tags: cassandra

I have 6 keyspaces in cassandra database. I want to migrate all my keyspaces schemas in another cassandra database. How can I do it at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DESCRIBE SCHEMA;
```

will give you DDL statements needed to recreate the non-system keyspaces and tables on a new cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can run following command to write the scema in cql file

`cqlsh -e "Desc keyspace keyspacename" > 'out.cql'`

and then use `SOURCE` to import cql file on another host OR `cqlsh -f out.cql optionalHostname`